# Gradle: How to pipe into a Exec task

Tags: gradle, groovy

I need to provide a default "yes" to a command I try to execute with Gradle.

So the moment I run:

```
./gradlew mytask
```

it should execute something like:

```sh
yes | <path-to-script-or-command>
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only one input to the command, you can do:

```java
task mytask(type: Exec) {
  commandLine "my-command"
  standardInput = new ByteArrayInputStream("yes".getBytes())
}
```

If you need it to be interactive, use `standardInput = System.in`.

I am not aware of a way to provide multiple fixed inputs though (e.g. the command first asks for one input, and after that another).